# Using php mt_rand() function

Tags: php, mysql

Am trying to use the php mt_rand() function to produce for me a unique number to be used as a unique identifier for a row in the database. Can it pick a number it had previously picked from the range 1, 1000000. My code is as follows echo mt_rand(1, 1000000);?>
Thanks for your continued help

Comment: yes it can. what is wrong with mysql primary key as auto-increment?

Comment: I definitely wouldn't recommend using any kind of `rand( )` to mimic a serialization of a database index. `auto-increment` is the way to go

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it will produce duplicates. It's just random, not unique. 
The easiest solution is to use an auto-increment column. If you don't want it to be sequential, you have a couple options. These are the two I would look at first:

https://github.com/ramsey/uuid

http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php